# Why domain names are backwards?

Tags: dns, domain-name

I realize that this question might not make sense to some, but I was just curious of why the domain names built starting from most specific and ending with most global identifier.

www.google.com

[most specific].[2nd level].[top level]

All other tree traversing formats, syntax conventions and identifiers (at least ones that I'm aware of) start with the most global namespace and end with the most specific node.

- **Filepath:** /root/subfolder1/subfolder2/file
- **Component:** com.android.notepad.NoteEditor
- **Object:** rootObject.subObject1.subObject2
- **IP:** 1.2.3.4
- **Newsgroups:** comp.lang.java.help
- **Phone numbers:** +1-555-555-1234

So I guess my question is whether there is any productive reason behind this special treatment of domain names by specifying them backwards, or it was just decided by throwing a coin?

EDIT:

More examples of forward conventions:

- **Address (Russia):** Country, City, Street House/Apt
- **Date (Japanese and DB):** YYYY-MM-DD
- **Time**: HH:mm:ss

Examples of Backward conventions:

- **Address (US):** Street House/Apt, City, State, Country
- **Date (European):** DD/MM/YYYY

The most specific first makes sense when addressing is identifiable easier and happens more often on local scale.

Mixed order:

- **Date (US):** MM/DD/YYYY - While Month gives more meaning to the Day, the Year is moved to be the last, because it less needed to uniquely identify the date in day-to-day use.

Comment: I've used minis where the filesystem was <file>.<directory> (just two levels)

Comment: +1 I want to know too! Great broad examples btw.

Comment: When you send a letter, the country comes last as well.

Comment: @Debilski - While this is true for US, it is not a global convention. In Russia, for example, it's Country first, then City, then Street, and then House/Apt. Although it is a smart system to write least specific in address, because historically, most of communication happened on local level, and less frequently on more global, so it was a solution for redundancy. It makes much less sense in domain names.

Comment: So that when you play them backwards you hear beatles songs.

Comment: @Unirgy: Interesting. Did not know that about the Russian convention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the book "Where the Wizards Stay Up Late" for details on how host names came to be.   It's really more like a coin flip.  Paul Vixie, the godfather of DNS and BIND is still alive (and I think in SoCal), he could probably answer it better than I.

I often thought of writing a browser addon that allows left to right hierarchical URLs in place of the current right to left.

P

Answer (score 3):

Reading through these:

- http://www.livinginternet.com/i/iw_dns_history.htm
- http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc819.txt

It seems like it was just following the convention.